# com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base error when running ionic cordova run android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

Full error

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is
>   being requested by various other libraries at [[16.5.0,16.5.0],
>   [16.4.0,16.4.0]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check
>   your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

I have tried multiple solutions:

I've tried removing the cordova-plugin-firebase issue so I can run this

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue
```

but when I do remove it I am getting:

> Uninstalling cordova-plugin-firebase from android Android Studio
>   project detected Error during processing of action! Attempting to
>   revert... Uh oh! ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\user\Documents\app1\test\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml'

I have also tried replacing these values from project.properties from:

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
```

to:

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8 
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0 
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1 
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4
```

But I am getting an error for each of the `com.google.firebase` line

> > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.0.4 .   Searched in the following locations:
> >           file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .pom
> >           file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .jar
> >           file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .pom
> >           file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .jar
> >           file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .pom
> >           file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .jar
> >           https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .pom
> >           https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .jar
> >           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .pom
> >           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .jar
> >           https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .pom
> >           https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .jar
> >           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .pom
> >           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-perf/11.0.4
> >     /firebase-perf-11.0.4 .jar   Required by:
> >           project :app

Comment: Have you found a solution? Have the same Problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Setting exact versions for firebase plugin dependencies is the fix you're looking for. The true reason for this issue is dependency conflicts caused by Google API update on May 7th.

But moving on, it's impossible to tell what your next exact issue is from the information you provided, however, one of your plugins is still requesting `firebase-perf-11.0.4` and it really does not exist at any of the paths `gradle` is looking at.

What you should do is find out which other plugin might be trying to download `firebase-perf-11.0.4` as a dependency. But first, open your project in Android Studio to see whether such a dependency even exists.

Comment: How would I go about finding where this dependency is on android studio?

Comment: Dependencies are usually defined in your app/build.gradle file, however, you could also just search  your entire project for "11.0.4" or something like that. Preferences -> Keymap to find out what the shortcut is